# Targeting an element with jQuery depending on JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a dynamically generated form which I get from an asynchronous AJAX call and I have some settings provided in a JSON object. I want to target one field specifically with jQuery, so I load the JSON data to a JS variable to work with it:

```
var jsonData = {{response.write(session.j_jsondata, escape=False)}};
/*
I'm using Web2Py, so the part between the double curly braces is equal to:
{'fields': [{'required': 'true', 'type': 'mtext', 'name': 'desc'}]}
*/
```

The data gets loaded correctly to the variable, but then when I want to target something with a name from jsonData.fields[somenumber].name it doesn't work.. I've tried it like this:

```
jQuery("form [name="+jsonData['fields'][i]['name']+"]")
```

I get no error. Any ideas why it's not targeting the expected element? Thanks!

Edit:
I tried changing the structure a bit. Instead of using name I chose ID (I updated the template view as well ofc) and switched  to

```
jQuery("#"+jsonData['fields'][i]['name'])
```

but still no cigar. It probably has some problems with tha fact that the field is generated after an AJAX call, but that's wierd because the script is called after the form is generated. So the last thing that happens is the execution of this script which targets the form element, yet it doesn't work. Sorcery.

Comment: Does `i` have the correct value? Since you don't know (I assume) whether the selector is generated correctly or not, set a breakpoint and expect the variables. To learn how to do that (if you not do already), have a look at http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, we can say that i = 0, this isn't the problem - everything works when I use a specific element ID - the problem is in jQuery("form [name="+jsonData['fields'][i]['name']+"]") but I don't know where :(

Comment: As I said, debug! We cannot run the code, so we cannot do that for you. Call `console.log("form [name="+jsonData['fields'][i]['name']+"]")` just before the selection and have a look what the output is. Is the selector correct? And are you executing this call when the form exists (since it is loaded via Ajax)?

Comment: yep, it returns "form [name=desc]" and desc is the name of the element which I want to target

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem with a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo, then we might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing on a local webpage, I noticed that you cannot have a space between the form and opening square bracket, so your selector should read:

```
jQuery("form[name="+jsonData['fields'][i]['name']+"]")
```

Cheers,

Terence.

Comment: Depends on what you are looking for. The space is the descendant selector. The OP's selector searches for an element with a certain name inside each form (which makes sense, since form controls have names), while yours searches for a form element with that name. The semantic is different.

Comment: Perhaps instead of specifying "form [name]" then, you should consider specifying "form input[name]" - I'm pretty sure you cannot supply a name as a selector, if you see what I mean. (Or form select[name] depending on what types of inputs you have)

Comment: But I have a form which contains an element with a name.. It's not the name of the form..

Comment: There is no problem in using an attribute selector on its own, it's completely valid. See: http://jsfiddle.net/cCDs2/.

Comment: Very strange, would adding classes to the inputs or fields be an option at all? Go around the naming issue entirely.

Comment: In addition, does the name have spaces in it at all? If so, consider putting quotation marks around it, as that will cause issues also.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's because the quotations for the attribute selector is missing. Try this:

```
$('form [name="'+jsonData['fields'][i]['name']+'"]')
```

Comment: Assuming everything else is correct, this is the most likely reason.

Comment: ...but if the name is a single word, it should also work without the quotation marks.

Comment: then i assume `jsonData['fields'][i]['name']` does not give you the right value...